# Estoy intentando cargar un xml a una base de datos en azure pero no me deja hacerlo desde un archivo local ¿Qué me recomiendan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, xml, openxml

La cuestión es que estoy haciendo una práctica de mi clase de bases de datos y tengo poca experiencia con SQL. Ya tengo las tablas donde se debe guardar la información creadas y obviamente también tengo el XML. Lo que pasa es que cuando abro el archivo con:

```
SET @xmlData = (
                SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'ruta en mi pc', SINGLE_BLOB)
                AS xmlData
                );
```

Me dice el error: Cannot bulk load because the file "dataset/Datos_Tarea3.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null). ¿Al parecer el error es que la función BULK de azure solo deja leer datos que están en el mismo servidor? Mi pregunta es, hay manera de leerlo localmente manteniendo la conexión o es más fácil simplemente pasar la base a local y así me evito este  error? Cabe recalcar que no es necesario tener la base conectada a azure en la tarea, lo tengo así solo porque quería aprender a conectarlo. Estoy usando microsoft sql server management studio.

Comment: El BULK INSERT de SQL Server SIEMPRE funciona leyendo archivos que están en el mismo servidor donde corre la BD. Cómo podría la BD, allá en azure, resolver una ruta en tu terminal? O lo pones allá o instalas la BD acá

Comment: Y adónde tendría que subir el archivo? Porque lo intenté y no encontré cómo/dónde

Comment: Mi conocimiento de Azure es nulo. Pero eso seguro está documentado. Si no has resuelto mañana, te ayudo a buscar

Answer (score 0):

Según [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#f-import-data-from-a-file-in-azure-blob-storage), Azure SQL sólo soporta leer desde un Blob Storage.

Así pues, es necesario configurar el acceso a ese storage (el external data source) EN el SQL Server. Un ejemplo con un CSV (el que se muestra en la documentación, lo dejo acá) sería:

```
--> Optional - a MASTER KEY is not required if a DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL is not required because the blob is configured for public (anonymous) access!
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourStrongPassword1';
GO
--> Optional - a DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL is not required because the blob is configured for public (anonymous) access!
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = '******srt=sco&sp=rwac&se=2017-02-01T00:55:34Z&st=2016-12-29T16:55:34Z***************';

-- NOTE: Make sure that you don't have a leading ? in SAS token, and
-- that you have at least read permission on the object that should be loaded srt=o&sp=r, and
-- that expiration period is valid (all dates are in UTC time)

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://****************.blob.core.windows.net/invoices'
          , CREDENTIAL = MyAzureBlobStorageCredential --> CREDENTIAL is not required if a blob is configured for public (anonymous) access!
);

BULK INSERT Sales.Invoices
FROM 'inv-2017-12-08.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage');
```